# Como maximizar una pantalla de CV2 python

Tags: python, opencv, cv2

tengo una duda estoy trabajando con la libreria de openCv en python para mostrar unas imagenes, pero no encuentro como hacer que la ventana se muestre de manera maximizada.
adjunto mi programa

```
for n in range(5):
        imagen = cv2.imread("fotos/imagen"+str(n)+".png")        
        res = cv2.resize(imagen, dsize=(ancho,alto),interpolation=cv2.INTER_CUBIC)
        cv2.imshow("hola",res)
        cv2.waitKey(3000)
        if n < 4:
            cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

La imagen se adapta en automatico al ancho y alto de mi pantalla, pero sale de manera minimizada, y movida, y aun usando moveWindow de igual cv2 para posicionarlo nunca queda como queda a menos que le de maximizar, pero quiero que desde el principio siempre salga la ventana maximizada, alguien sabe como se hace eso?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

##### Algunas notas

No es lo mismo una ventana maximizada, que es un estado en la que dicha se encuentra, que una ventana que aparenta estar maximizada. Además, cuando el tamaño es el mismo que el de la pantalla, la ventana se extiende por debajo de la barra de tareas, lo cual sería molesto para visualizar la parte inferior de la imagen.

##### Usando la ventana de opencv

Si bien no se puede maximizar la ventana con lo ofrecido por opencv, si se puede cambiar el tamaño. Lamentablemente, la ventana aparece movida y moveWindow no es preciso con las coordenadas. Probé mover la ventana usando coordenadas negativas y queda muy a la derecha (-15x) o muy a la izquierda (-16x).

opencv no ofrece formas de obtener la id de la ventana (no el nombre) y la librería de interfáz grafica usada puede variar (no encontré información sobre como se eligen las librerías)

Un truco, que no sería multiplataforma, es obtener la ventana activa (asumiendo que esta es la de opencv) usando la api de Windows y maximizarla. En base a [una pregunta del sitio en inglés](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2790825/how-can-i-maximize-a-specific-window-with-python) (requiere pywin32)

```
import win32gui, win32con
import numpy as np
import cv2

img = np.ones([768, 1366])

cv2.imshow("image", img)

# agrega estas dos lineas luego de imshow
hwnd = win32gui.GetForegroundWindow()
win32gui.ShowWindow(hwnd, win32con.SW_MAXIMIZE)

cv2.waitKey(0)
```

Otra opción es la pantalla completa, solo agrega estas dos lineas antes de imshow:

```
cv2.namedWindow("image", cv2.WINDOW_NORMAL)
cv2.setWindowProperty("image", cv2.WND_PROP_FULLSCREEN, cv2.WINDOW_FULLSCREEN)
```

##### Usando un módulo de gui

Finalmente, las ventanas generadas por opencv están destinadas simplemente para ver las imagenes durante las pruebas, no tanto para entornos de producción. Si leemos la [documentación de opencv en c](https://docs.opencv.org/3.4/d7/dfc/group__highgui.html#ga5afdf8410934fd099df85c75b2e0888b)

> While OpenCV [...] can
> be used within functionally rich UI frameworks (such as Qt*,
> WinForms*, or Cocoa*) or without any UI at all, sometimes there it is
> required to try functionality quickly and visualize the results. This
> is what the HighGUI module has been designed for.

Que traducido usando google y revisado (perdon), sería:

> Si bien OpenCV [...] puede usarse dentro de marcos de UI
> funcionalmente ricos (como Qt*, WinForms* o Cocoa*) o sin ninguna UI,
> a veces es necesario probar la funcionalidad rápidamente y visualizar
> los resultados. Para esto se ha diseñado el módulo HighGUI [Nota del traductor: highgui es el módulo que muestra las imagenes en ventanas].

Por lo tanto, te recomiendo recurrir a modulos como tkinter, pyqt, pyside2, etc para mostrar las imagenes, a pesar de no tener todas las funcionalidades de las ventanas generadas por opencv. Estas librerías, sobre todo los bindings de Qt (pyside y pyqt), tienen formas muy sencillas de maximizar una ventana.

El código necesario para pasar un array de numpy (que representan imagenes en opencv) dependerá de la librería que interfáz grafica que uses. Si extiendo la respuesta con este tema, me alejaría mucho de la duda original.